# Using fs.createReadStream in electron renderer process

Tags: node.js, electron, fs

The problem:
I want to upload a file from an electron renderer process using axios but creating a FormData object using `fs.createReadStream` doesn't seem to work in the renderer process. However, if I use electron IPC to send the filename to the main process (not shown in attached repo) all works as expected.

I don't understand why I can use some fs methods in the renderer process but creating a FormData object using createReadStream doesn't work.

The repo showing this is at: https://github.com/marcolarosa/electron-fs-example

The README describes how to run the code and shows output snippets with an explanation of what is seen vs what is expected. But in short:

- If I exec electron with my app code, it all seems to work as expected. The file is processed on the server by the restify body parser plugin.
- If I exec electron with a main script that loads the code - it doesn't. The file doesn't seem to get uploaded. It's as if fs.createReadStream doesn't work in the renderer process even though other fs methods do (not shown in this repo but they do work in the source repo that this came from).

Any ideas? I'd just like to understand the behaviour.